# Rearrange array by loop and next element value check

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to rearrange my array by checking using loop and next value match.

Here if current element value is 0 and next element value is 5

it will check by $nextCheck value

if number of element before 5 < $nextCheck

i want to change that value from 0 to 1

My current array like this

```
$arr_calendar = array (
   '2020-11-07' => Array
    (
        '18:00' => 5,
        '18:15' => 5,
        '18:30' => 0,
        '18:45' => 0,
        '19:15' => 0,
        '19:30' => 0,
        '20:00' => 5,
        '20:15' => 5,
        '20:30' => 5,
        '20:45' => 5,
        '21:00' => 5,
        '21:15' => 5,
        '21:30' => 5,
        '21:45' => 5,
    )
);
```

My expected array will be like this

```
    Array
(
    [2020-11-07] => Array
        (
            [18:00] => 5 
            [18:15] => 5
            [19:30] => 0
            [18:45] => 0
            [19:15] => 1
            [19:30] => 1
            [20:00] => 5
            [20:15] => 5
            [20:30] => 5
            [20:45] => 5
            [21:00] => 5
            [21:15] => 5
            [21:30] => 5
            [21:45] => 5
        )

)
```

For this I tried like this

```
$arr_calendar = array (
       '2020-11-07' => Array
        (
            '18:00' => 5,
            '18:15' => 5,
            '18:30' => 0,
            '18:45' => 0,
            '19:15' => 0,
            '19:30' => 0,
            '20:00' => 5,
            '20:15' => 5,
            '20:30' => 5,
            '20:45' => 5,
            '21:00' => 5,
            '21:15' => 5,
            '21:30' => 5,
            '21:45' => 5,
        )
    );
$nextCheck =3;
foreach ($arr_calendar as $date => $arr_hour) {
    
    $arr_hour_checked = array();
            foreach ($arr_hour as $hour => $disable) {
                $arr_hour_checked[] = array(
                    'hour' => $hour,
                    'disable' => $disable
                );
            }
            $arr_hour_checked[] = array(// Fake for last item
                'hour' => '',
                'disable' => 99
            );
    
    for($index1 = 0; $index1 < count($arr_hour_checked); $index1++) {
       
        
        if ($arr_hour_checked[$index1]['disable'] == 0) {
            for($index2 = $index1 + 1; $index2 < count($arr_hour_checked); $index2++) {
                if ($index2 - $index1 < $nextCheck) {
                    for ($step = $index1; $step < $index2; $step++) {
                        $arr_calendar[$date][$hour] = 1;

                    }
                } else {
                    for ($step = $index2 - $nextCheck + 1; $step < $index2; $step++) {
                        $arr_calendar[$date][$hour] = 1;
                    }
                }
                $index1 = $index2 - 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r ($arr_calendar);
```

Please suggest what I missed here
[**FIDDLE**](https://3v4l.org/FmZmZ)

Sorry for my english. if nextCheck = 3

**after one 0 two 1 will come.**
**Q:** if sequence 0,5,0,5

**Result:**  it will be 1,5,1,5

**Q:** if sequence 1,5,1,5

**Result:**   it will be 1,5,1,5

**Q:**
if
5,5,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,5

**Result:**
then serial can be like this

5,5,0,0,1,1,5,5,5,0,1,1,5,0,0,0,1,1,5

Comment: Can you elaborate? Basically set all 0s to 1s till $nextCheck - 1 ?

Comment: Sorry for my english. if nextCheck = 3 then serial can be like this 5,5,0,0,1,1,5,5,5,0,1,1,5,0,0,0,1,1,5 @nice_dev

Comment: after one 0 two 1 will come. if sequence 0,5,0,5 it will be 1,5,1,5 @nice_dev

Comment: So `0,5,0,5` should be `0,1,1,5,0,1,1,5` ..

Comment: @nice_dev no, 0,5,0,5 will be 1,5,1,5 if 0 more than 2    like 0,0,0,5 then it will be 0,1,1,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem statement isn't completely clear*, however it looks like you want to set all 0s to 1s before 5. The total number of zeroes set to 1 would be `$nextCheck - 1`.

```
foreach($arr_calendar as $date => &$value){
    $count = 0;
    foreach(array_reverse($value) as $time => $val){
        if($val == 5) $count = $nextCheck;
        else if($val == 0 && $count > 1){
            $value[$time] = 1;
            $count--;
        }
    }
}
```

So, you loop from last to first and whenever you get a value `5`, you set count to `$nextCheck`. For all 0s coming after `5`, you would set it to `1` till `$count - 1` times.

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/AXsVC